# Vue not displaying data from data object

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJs and created `test.vue` in `pages` directory. Here is my code in `test.vue`.

```
<template>
  <div> 
    <h1 style="font-size: 30px">{{ message }} </h1>
    <h1 style="font-size: 30px"> Messsage here </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: {
    message: 'sdfsd'
  }
}
</script>
```

But `{{ message }}` not displaying. What is the problem?

Comment: data Must Be a Function
 https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` needs to be a `function` so that each instance can maintain an independent copy of the returned data object.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       message: 'sdfsd'
    }
  }
}
```

Read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)